# Spring tool mailSender.send(email) returns NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, email, spring-mvc

I'm trying to send a mail using Spring tool (via JavaMail library). I follow the directions on this link: http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/sending-e-mail-with-spring-mvc#SpringEmail.

Firstly I thought that the bean was incorrect, but it seems correct to me.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl"
    id="mailSender">

    <!-- SMTP settings -->
    <property value="smtp.gmail.com" name="host" />
    <property value="587" name="port" />
    <property value="xxxxxx@gmail.com" name="username" />
    <property value="***********" name="password" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <!-- additional properties specific to JavaMail -->
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.transport.protocol">smtp</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The Implementation file I created is as follows:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.mail.MailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.SimpleMailMessage;

import gr.hua.intranet.model.Representative;

 public class mailDAOImp implements mailDAO {

private DataSource dataSource;
private MailSender mailSender;

public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
}

@Override
public void SentConfirmation(Representative customer) {

    mail NewMail = new mail();

    NewMail.fastMailSet(customer, "Your registration confirmed", "Now you can log in to our Systems.\n"
            + "Username: " + customer.getAAM() + "\n Password: " + customer.getUsername(), null);

    SimpleMailMessage email = new SimpleMailMessage();
    email.setTo(NewMail.Address);
    email.setSubject(NewMail.Sbj);
    email.setText(NewMail.Msg);

    // sends the e-mail
    mailSender.send(email);
}

@Override
public void SentMail(Representative representative, String Reason, String msg) {

    mail NewMail = new mail();

    NewMail.fastMailSet(representative, "Newsletter: " + Reason, msg, null);

    SimpleMailMessage email = new SimpleMailMessage();
    email.setTo(NewMail.Address);
    email.setSubject(NewMail.Sbj);
    email.setText(NewMail.Msg);

    // sends the e-mail
    mailSender.send(email);
}

@Override
public void SentNewsLater(String Reason, String msg) {

    String query = "SELECT * FROM NewsletterRecivers WHERE 1";

    Representative representative = null;
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try {
        con = dataSource.getConnection();
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {

            representative = new Representative();
            representative.setMail(rs.getString("Mail"));
            SentMail(representative, Reason, msg);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            rs.close();
            ps.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void SenRegistrationCompletle(Representative customer) {

    mail NewMail = new mail();

    NewMail.fastMailSet(customer, "Newsletter registration is successful.",
            "From now on you' ll recive newslatters.", null);
    SimpleMailMessage email = new SimpleMailMessage();
    email.setTo(NewMail.Address);
    email.setSubject(NewMail.Sbj);
    email.setText(NewMail.Msg);

    // sends the e-mail
    mailSender.send(email);

}

}
```

I the message seems not being null but `mailSender.send(email)` gives me:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at gr.hua.intranet.model.mailDAOImp.SenRegistrationCompletle(mailDAOImp.java:107)
>       at gr.hua.intranet.model.NLReciverDAOImp.Add(NLReciverDAOImp.java:56)
>       at gr.hua.intranet.model.NLReciverDAOImp.CheckAndADD(NLReciverDAOImp.java:23)
>       at gr.hua.intranet.ReceiverController.addUser(ReceiverController.java:29)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag - Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available as request attribute
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:141)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getBindStatus(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:178)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.getPropertyPath(AbstractDataBoundFormElementTag.java:198)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.autogenerateFor(LabelTag.java:129)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.resolveFor(LabelTag.java:119)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.LabelTag.writeTagContent(LabelTag.java:89)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractFormTag.doStartTagInternal(AbstractFormTag.java:102)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79)
>       at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.nl.NL_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005flabel_005f0(NL_jsp.java:277)
>       at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.nl.NL_jsp._jspService(NL_jsp.java:166)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:262)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1180)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:950)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:277)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

MVC - Spring - Java Masters show me the way :) .

Comment: Always show the given Stacktrace when you ask about an exception. Java masters are not smart enough to figure out without it ;-)

Comment: With the stack trace I mean the whole stacktrace...

Comment: It doesn't help that you're not following Java naming conventions.